# Loop to append a list of strings to the strings in another list

Tags: python, web-scraping

I tried to make the title more clear but it really takes a lot more wording that.

What I need done:

I have a list of URLs.  In each URL(the actual website), there are file names contained in the HTML.  I have scraped a website to get a list of each URL and another list of all the file names contained in each of those URLs, and all the filenames are in the same list.

I need to append the names of each file in each URL to their respective pages (preceding URL to the filename).

Example of the lists:

```
list1 = ['www.something.com/a/','www.something.com/b/','www.something.com/c/']
list2 = ['adam.html','addison.html','bob.html','boris.html','claire.html','clarence.html']
```

The structure of the URLs is alphabetical and each filename starts with the corresponding letter.

For example:  I want to take `www.something.com/a/` and append all filenames to that creating list of full URLs (and their file names) like `www.something.com/a/adam.html`, `www.something.com/a/addison.html`.

After `/a/` is done, the loops moves on to `www.something.com/b/` and appends `b` filenames like `www.something.com/b/bob`, `www.something.com/b/boris`

I've thought about this for a while.  Obviously the first obstacle is that the lists I'm combining are different lengths.  Also I don't currently have the list of filenames separated by their preceding/home urls.  I thought maybe I could loop them into a dictionary/array with the keys being the letters or home urls but I'm not sure how that's done as I'm quite new to all of this.

Edit to add code:

```
def get_top_urls(letters):
    top_url_list = []
    for letter in letters:
        top_url_list.append("http://www.basketball-reference.com/players/%s" % letter)`

    player_urls = []
    for i in top_url_list:
        result = re.findall("\/([a-z]+[0-9][0-9]\W[a-z]+)", str(urlopen(i).read()))
        player_urls.append(result) 
    return player_urls


    #for i in top_url_list:



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It's `top_urls` and `player_urls` that I need to append to one another to get a list of all the URLs I ultimately need.
Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Can you please write a sample of both lists?

Comment: What's the difficulty? Seems like a simple task in python - what issues are you having, what have you tried?

Comment: Please provide some code that you have tried if you want help. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: @Walter_Ritzel I've updated with examples of the lists.

Comment: @AChampion I've tried just appending one list to the other and it that doesn't work because they're of different lengths.  I end up getting 26 completed urls with the first 26 filenames and then a list of the rest of the filenames instead of appending all of them to their appropriate URLs.

I've also tried writing the loop I'm thinking of but need a way to separate each filename of each letter into their own indeces so that the loop knows which when to stop adding filenames to a certain URL and move onto the next.

Comment: @munircontractor updated with code.

Comment: @ffledgling  I don't believe that would work because 1 list is 26 items long (the alphabet but in the form of URLs ending in the letter) and one is a list of filenames that all start with different letters.  There might be 50 that start with 'a' and 150 that start with 'b', 35 that start with 'c' and so on.  I want each 'a' URL to precede each 'a' filename and each 'b' URL to precede each 'b' filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and all the filenames are in the same list.

That's your actual problem; instead of chucking your results into flat lists and then trying to sort them out later, just use a dictionary to keep them associated properly:

```
def get_urls(letters):
    url_dict = {}
    for letter in letters:
        top_url = "http://whatever.com/{}/".format(letter)
        result = re.findall("\/([a-z]+[0-9][0-9]\W[a-z]+)", str(urlopen(top_url).read()))
        url_dict[top_url] = result
    return url_dict
```

Now your `url_dict` looks something like:

```
{'http://whatever.com/a/': ['addison.html', 'avery.html'],
 'http://whatever.com/b/': ['bob.html', 'boris.html'],
 ...
}
```

And you can get all the urls by joining appropriately:

```
all_urls = [''.join(top, name) for top, names in url_dict.items() for name in names]
```

Note that if all you want is the final list you could just join in the original function and return the final list to begin with:

```
get_all_urls(letters):
    urls = []
    for letter in letters:
        top_url = ...
        players = re.findall(...)
        for player in players:
            urls.append(''.join(top_url, player))
    return urls
```

Comment: very nice.  Thanks!  This is what I was looking for!

Comment: I do have a question though.  I notice you have `str(urlopen(i).read())))`

Is the `i` a typo or is this some shortcut for counting in the second list?

Comment: I just copied that part from your code without correcting it, my bad. Fixed!

Comment: Thanks so much for you help.  Hopefully last question: what is the `' '` in the `urls.append....` statement?

I think it's that is causing an error for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list1 = ['www.something.com/a/','www.something.com/b/','www.something.com/c/']
list2 = ['adam.html','addison.html','bob.html','boris.html','claire.html','clarence.html']

list3 = []

for item in list1:
    letter = item[item.rfind('/')-1:item.rfind('/')]
    print(item)
    for each in list2:
        if each[0] == letter:
            list3.append(item + each)

print (list3)
```